# Install a PowerShell utility for SQL Server Agent?

Tags: powershell, windows-server, sql-server-agent

I want to be able to use [Az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=powershell) in a Powershell script being run as a SQL Server Agent job. However, I haven't been able to install the CLI for the SQL Server Agent service. How can I install this for the SQL Server Agent or otherwise accomplish this? (I might need to install another utility afterward to compress a file as well.)

I attempted to run the [given PS Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=powershell#powershell) in a SQL Agent Job. I attempted to run with a PSSession as the `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` user (I don't know that I set the session up properly). I attempted to set the Execution Policy to LocalMachine before running the MSI from powershell.

Comment: I would check the log files in the SQL Server.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and the log files are in the explorer under Management.